Clerk user details not updating untill refreshed in NextJs project
Whenever new user signs in with gmail and password, user details does not update. It shows the last signed in user details.
I am using mongoDb as my database and zustand for state management.
this is the function which i am calling.
export const saveCurrentUserToMongoDB = async () => {
  try {
    const clerkUserdata = await currentUser();
    const mongoDbUserPayload = {
      name: clerkUserdata?.firstName + " " + clerkUserdata?.lastName,
      email: clerkUserdata?.emailAddresses[0].emailAddress,
      clerkUserID: clerkUserdata?.id,
      profilePic: clerkUserdata?.imageUrl,
      isAdmin: false,
      isAcive: true,
    };

    const newUser = new UserModel(mongoDbUserPayload);
    await newUser.save();

    return {
      success: true,
      message: "User Saved to mongoDB",
      data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newUser)),
    };
  } catch (error: any) {
    return {
      success: false,
      message: error.message,
    };
  }
};

export const getCurrentUserFromMongoDB = async () => {
  try {
    const clerkUserdata = await currentUser();

    // check if user already exists

    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ clerkUserID: clerkUserdata?.id });
    if (user)
      return {
        success: true,
        data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)),
      };

    const saveUserResponse = await saveCurrentUserToMongoDB();
    if (saveUserResponse) {
      return {
        success: true,
        data: saveUserResponse.data,
      };
    }

    return {
      success: false,
      message: "User not found in MongoDb",
    };
  } catch (error: any) {
    return {
      success: false,
      message: error.message,
    };
  } 
};


user store for zustand
const usersGlobalStore = create((set) => ({
  currentUserData: null,
  setCurrentUserData: (data: IUser) => set({ currentUserData: data }),
}));

export default usersGlobalStore;

export interface IUserGlobalStore {
  currentUserData: IUser | null;
  setCurrentUserData: (data: IUser) => void;
}

my logout function inisde a client component
const onLogOut = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      await signOut({ redirectUrl: "/sign-in" });

      message.success("LoggedOut successfully");
    } catch (error: any) {
      message.error("Failed to Logout");
    } finally {
      setShowSideBar(false);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

I have also tried to clear localstorage and cookies in the logout function. That did not help.
